# Isometric JavaScript framework/engine?

Tags: javascript, game-development

I will be creating a small isometric game with JS. There are a lot of different frameworks and engines out there. Please help me to find the right one for my needs:

In my game the world will not be expandable - so the ground and its borders are already given in the beginning and can't be changed. One can place an object from a library on the ground and also delete it. One can zoom in/out and drag the whole map (if it’s zoomed) That’s basically it.

I’ve seen these engines (but I’m sure there are more): [Craftyjs](http://craftyjs.com), [pp3Diso](http://www.prelude-prod.fr/demo/pp3diso/), [Isogenic](http://isogenicengine.com), [JSIso](http://jsiso.com).

Please help me to find the right one.

Comment: Do you care about price? open-source? any other features you can list?

Comment: well it's ok if it's not for free - but I don't want to pay too much... Basically these are the features: placing/moving/deleting objects; zooming/moving the entire map; some animated movements of objects (sprites) - but these are very limited and the user can't control them; should run on IE 10, mozilla and webkit

Answer (score 1):

I am obviously biased (being the main author), but would recommend [WADE isometric](http://www.clockworkchilli.com/index.php/developers/sample/5), which comes with a step-by-step guide to making what you described above. We used it to make [this game](http://www.zirma.net), which works well on mobile browsers and took 2 people about 3 weeks.

[Isogenic](http://isogenicengine.com/) is also very good, especially in the networking aspect, but it's a bit more on the expensive side.

[Crafty](http://craftyjs.com/demos/isometric/)'s support for isometric seems a bit more limited - but that's free, so I suppose it's a matter of finding the right balance between price and features.

Comment: Hi Gio - sorry for the late response... meanwhile I have tried the sheetengine (also canvas based like wade) and have found some limitations. My map has 3600 tiles and objects (intersecion is needed) and I need to see them all at once when I zoom out. Sheetengine became too slow with this - how about WADE - do you think it would handle it?

Comment: @KoshaMisa I haven't tried sheetengine, so I can't comment on that. WADE uses a quadtree system so it ever only draws what is visible at the time, and therefore has no problems with large maps -  provided that the whole map isn't visible at the same time. Even if it is, if you don't move the camera it knows not to redraw the part of the screen that hasn't changed. You may run into memory issues if you want to do this on a low-end mobile device, depending on the resolution and number of your textures. I'd be happy to discuss more details on the [WADE forum](http://www.clockworkchilli.com/forum)